# Loading external scripts with Userscript works with Fx 4, but fails in Fx 3.6

Tags: javascript, firefox3.6, userscripts, firefox4

Here's the code, not abridged (it's shortish):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Manga ChapterReader
// @license        MIT/X11 + Attribution (passcod)
// @namespace      http://www.mangareader.net
// @include        http://www.mangareader.net/*
// @description    Displays full chapters from MangaReader.net in a simpler interface.
// @author         passcod
// @version        10.331
// ==/UserScript==

// version format: y.z
function START(array_of_scripts_to_load, callback) {
    document.documentElement.innerHTML = '<head></head><body></body>';
    for ( i in array_of_scripts_to_load) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = array_of_scripts_to_load[i];
        var evl = new Object();
        evl.handleEvent = function (e) {
            callback();
        };
        script.addEventListener('load', evl, true);
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }
}

var regular = /mangareader\.net\/[a-z0-9\-]+\/[0-9]+(\/.+)?/i, old = /mangareader\.net\/[0-9\-]+\/([a-z0-9\-]+)\/chapter-([0-9]+)\.htm/i;

if ( regular.test(window.location) ) {
    //START(['http://lib/libstore/jquery.js','http://scrap.book/userscripts/mangareader/index.js'],
    START(['http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js','https://bitbucket.org/passcod/scrap.book/raw/tip/userscripts/mangareader/index.js'],
    function() {
        $$$();
    });
}
else if ( old.test(window.location) ) {
    var parts = old.exec(window.location);
    window.location = 'http://www.mangareader.net/'+parts[1]+'/'+parts[2];
}
```

This works perfectly in Firefox 4.0b7 (Windows) and nightly (Linux), but it fails with Fx 3.6.x (Reports from 3.6, 3.6.2, and 3.6.12).

I can't see why.

Oh, wait... I use Scriptish on Fx 4... maybe this has to do with something?

But apart from that, I'm totally at loss. The scripts don't get loaded. It even looks like the `document.documentElement.innerHTML = '...'` line doesn't work... did it in Firebug and it erases the document to `<html></html>`, but nothing more happens afterward.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing the loaded scripts to execute immediately:

```
(function () { /* ... */ })();
```

and then removing the callbacks.

There was no problem with the browser, but in the reaction time. For some reason, the userscript finished too early in Fx 4.